# Python Pandas Dataframe - Create new column using a conditional/applying a function based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I'm new to Python so I'm still getting to grips with it.

Essentially, in my Pandas Datframe I have a column 'Comments' and would like to create a new column called 'Readability' - where for non-null rows/values, I pass the 'Comments' value into textstat.flesch_reading_ease(). But if 'Comments' are null/NaN - the value in 'Readability' would simply be 0.0.
.
The NaN values are part of my analysis - so I don't want to omit them in this case.

#Pseudo
If null x -> 0.0 , else textstat.flesch_reading_ease(x)

See Image.

In terms of code, I have been building familiarity with pd.loc() - but I don't think it's viable in this case?

Alternatively, I have tried

```
repairs['Readibility'] = repairs['Comment'].apply(lambda x: 0.0 if x.isnull() else textstat.flesch_reading_ease(x))
```

This returns 'float' object has no attribute 'isnull'

Any ideas how to tweak my approach? I would also appreciate the why/how behind solutions.
Also happy to see 2/3 step answers if it's easier to understand :)

Thanks!

[Example of 'Comments' column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFsF1.png)//i.stack.imgur.com/cZAWQ.png

Comment: `repairs.loc['Comment'].isnull() == False, "Comment"].apply(textstat.flesch_reading_ease)` much simpler, let me know if that's something you were looking for and I'll add it as Answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
repairs['Readibility'] = repairs['Comment'].apply(lambda x: 0.0 if pd.isna(x) else textstat.flesch_reading_ease(x))
```

Another idea:

```
repairs['Readibility'] = 0
repairs['Readibility'] = repairs.loc['Comment'].notna(), "Comment"].apply(textstat.flesch_reading_ease)
```